# How to convert Text into Numeric in Mainframe

Tags: mainframe

I need to convert Numbers stored as Text datatype(left aligned) ranging from 2 to 4 digits to Numeric format(Right aligned) in Mainframes.

```
For eg,

Field1(Text left aligned)         Field2(Numeric Right aligned)
---------------------------------------------------------------
1000                                       1000           
11                                           11     
200                                         200
```

Can use SORT EZTRIEVE COBOL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a COBOL solution, try using `UNSTRING` and a `JUSTIFIED RIGHT` receiving field. Here is an example program (IBM Enterprise COBOL) to illustrate.

```
  IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.                       
    PROGRAM-ID. EXAMPLE1.                        
  DATA DIVISION.                                 
  WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                       
  01  SOURCE-DATA       PIC X(4).                
  01  DEST-DATA         PIC X(4) JUSTIFIED RIGHT. 
  PROCEDURE DIVISION.                            
      MOVE '123' TO SOURCE-DATA                  
      UNSTRING SOURCE-DATA DELIMITED BY SPACE    
          INTO DEST-DATA                         
      DISPLAY 'SOURCE >' SOURCE-DATA '<'         
      DISPLAY 'DEST   >' DEST-DATA '<'           

      MOVE '1' TO SOURCE-DATA                    
      UNSTRING SOURCE-DATA DELIMITED BY SPACE 
          INTO DEST-DATA                         
      DISPLAY 'SOURCE >' SOURCE-DATA '<'         
      DISPLAY 'DEST   >' DEST-DATA '<'           
      GOBACK                                     
      .
```

The output from this program is:

```
SOURCE >123 <    
DEST   > 123<    
SOURCE >1   <    
DEST   >   1<
```

Answer (score 1):

This works as well...

```
  IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.                       
    PROGRAM-ID. STR2NUM.                        
  DATA DIVISION.                                 
  WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                       
  01  SOURCE-DATA       PIC X(4).                
  01  DEST-DATA         PIC BBB9. 
  PROCEDURE DIVISION.                            
      MOVE '123' TO SOURCE-DATA                  
      UNSTRING SOURCE-DATA DELIMITED BY SPACE    
          INTO DEST-DATA                         
      DISPLAY 'SOURCE >' SOURCE-DATA '<'         
      DISPLAY 'DEST   >' DEST-DATA '<'           

      MOVE '1' TO SOURCE-DATA                    
      UNSTRING SOURCE-DATA DELIMITED BY SPACE 
          INTO DEST-DATA                         
      DISPLAY 'SOURCE >' SOURCE-DATA '<'         
      DISPLAY 'DEST   >' DEST-DATA '<'           
      GOBACK                                     
      .
```

Comment: This does not work. Firstly, with Enterprise Cobol, the target of an UNSTRING cannot be an edited field, so you get a Severe compile error "IGYPA3107-S   "UNSTRING INTO" identifier "DEST-DATA (NUMERIC-EDITED)" was invalid because it is one of the following: *an edited item*, an external floating point item, an alphabetic item with "B" in its "PICTURE" or a numeric item with "P" in its "PICTURE".  The statement was discarded.". Secondly, if it did work, the BBB in the PICture are for three actual blanks, so the data would get truncated to one digit/character.

Answer (score 0):

I'll beg to differ with the other two answers as they, IMO, are simply re-representing the source text as edited alphanumeric output. Here's my stab at it:

```
  IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.                       
  PROGRAM-ID. STR2NUM.                        
  DATA DIVISION.                                 
  WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.            
  01  WS-VARIABLES.           
    05  SRCE-DATA         PIC  X(4). 
    05  SRCE-DATA-R       PIC  X(4) JUST RIGHT.      
    05  DEST-DATA-N       PIC  9(4).         
    05  DEST-DATA         PIC  ZZZ9. 
  PROCEDURE DIVISION. 
      INITIALIZE WS-VARIABLES                           
      MOVE '11' TO SRCE-DATA                  
      UNSTRING SRCE-DATA DELIMITED BY SPACE    
          INTO SRCE-DATA-R
      INSPECT SRCE-DATA-R
          REPLACING ALL SPACES BY ZEROES
      MOVE SRCE-DATA-R TO DEST-DATA-N, DEST-DATA                         
      DISPLAY 'SOURCE >' SRCE-DATA '<'         
      DISPLAY 'DEST   >' DEST-DATA '<'           
      GOBACK                                     
      .
```

The DEST-DATA-N field has a true numeric version of the source data.

Comment: Since you are not worried about your "true numeric" being numeric, you can UNSTRING into DEST-DATA-N, which is right-justified, leading-zero filled. Saves INSPECT, and a MOVE and you'd not need to MOVE an alpha-numeric to a numeric.

Answer (score 0):

A more "verbose" answer than NealB's, less strain on the CPU.

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION. 
   PROGRAM-ID. STR2NUM. 
   DATA DIVISION. 
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION. 
   01  SOURCE-DATA                         PIC X(4). 
       88  SD-NO-DATA                      VALUE SPACE.
   01  FILLER REDEFINES SOURCE-DATA. 
       05  SOURCE-DATA-ALL                 PIC 9(4). 
   01  FILLER REDEFINES SOURCE-DATA. 
       05  SD-LEADING-1                    PIC 9. 
       05  SD-TRAILING-3                   PIC X(3). 
           88  SD-DATA-1-LEADING           VALUE SPACE.
   01  FILLER REDEFINES SOURCE-DATA. 
       05  SD-LEADING-2                    PIC 99. 
       05  SD-TRAILING-2                   PIC XX. 
           88  SD-DATA-2-LEADING           VALUE SPACE.
   01  FILLER REDEFINES SOURCE-DATA. 
       05  SD-LEADING-3                    PIC 9(3). 
       05  SD-TRAILING-1                   PIC X. 
           88  SD-DATA-3-LEADING           VALUE SPACE.
   01  DEST-DATA                           PIC 9(4). 
   PROCEDURE DIVISION. 
       MOVE '1234'                  TO SOURCE-DATA 
       PERFORM                      PROCESS-THE-DATA 
       MOVE '123'                   TO SOURCE-DATA 
       PERFORM                      PROCESS-THE-DATA 
       MOVE '12'                    TO SOURCE-DATA 
       PERFORM                      PROCESS-THE-DATA 
       MOVE '1'                     TO SOURCE-DATA 
       PERFORM                      PROCESS-THE-DATA 
       MOVE SPACE                   TO SOURCE-DATA 
       PERFORM                      PROCESS-THE-DATA 
       GOBACK 
       . 
   PROCESS-THE-DATA. 
       EVALUATE TRUE 
           WHEN SD-NO-DATA 
             MOVE ZERO              TO DEST-DATA
           WHEN SD-DATA-1-LEADING 
             MOVE SD-LEADING-1      TO DEST-DATA
           WHEN SD-DATA-2-LEADING 
             MOVE SD-LEADING-2      TO DEST-DATA
           WHEN SD-DATA-3-LEADING 
             MOVE SD-LEADING-3      TO DEST-DATA
           WHEN OTHER 
             MOVE SOURCE-DATA-ALL   TO DEST-DATA
       END-EVALUATE 

       DISPLAY 'SOURCE >' SOURCE-DATA '<' 
               'DEST   >' DEST-DATA '<' 
       .
```

Which gives:

```
SOURCE >1234<DEST   >1234<
SOURCE >123 <DEST   >0123<
SOURCE >12  <DEST   >0012<
SOURCE >1   <DEST   >0001<
SOURCE >    <DEST   >0000<
```