# Abend S0C7 error while moving data to COMP-3 fields

Tags: cobol, mainframe

Moving data to `COMP-3` fields after `UNSTRING`.

`UNSTRING` is working fine but I am not able to move data to `COMP-3` fields without an S0C7 data exception abend.

I think it is an issue with storing data.

Below is my COBOL program.

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.                              
 PROGRAM-ID. ADDPROG.                                  
 DATA DIVISION.                                        
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                            
    01 VALUEA         PIC X(20) VALUE '64.99|64.99'.   
    01 NOA            PIC S9(9)V9(02).                 
    01 NOB            PIC S9(9)V9(02).                 
    01 NOC            PIC S9(9)V99 COMP-3.             
    01 NOD            PIC S9(9)V99 COMP-3.             
 PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                   
  000-MAIN.                                            
     DISPLAY "EARLIER".                                
     DISPLAY 'NOA-' NOA.                               
     DISPLAY 'NOB-' NOB.                               
     DISPLAY "AFTER".                                  
     UNSTRING VALUEA                                   
     DELIMITED BY '|'                                  
     INTO NOA,NOB.          
     DISPLAY 'NOA-' NOA.    
     DISPLAY 'NOB-' NOB.    
     MOVE NOA TO NOC.       
     MOVE NOB TO NOD.       
     DISPLAY 'NOC-' NOC.    
     DISPLAY 'NOD-' NOD.    
     STOP RUN.
```

Output I am getting after compiling.

[image]

Please let me know is there any other way to move data to `COMP-3` fields or to avoid this error.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has two main problems. To see them you first have to understand that your `UNSTRING` into `NOA` and `NOB` works like any other character-to-character `MOVE`.
So it starts from the left and moves character after character until one field ends and if necessary adds some blanks to fill up the receiving field.

So problem one is that `NOA` contains the value left-justified while according to your `PIC`-clause it should be right-justified, so you would need an intermediate `PIC X(12) JUSTIFIED RIGHT` field that you `UNSTRING` to.

The second problem that is causing the S0C7 is that your `PIC`-clause does not include a decimal-point. The `V` specifies the implied *position* of the decimal point but it would not show on output nor is it handled correctly when parsing the field-contents. To have a field that correctly handles the decimal point you should have a `PIC S9(9)V.9(02)`.

Please also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964447/how-to-convert-text-into-numeric-in-mainframe).

Answer (score 0):

Your decimal data field are wrong just have . Like 01 NOA PIC S9(9).(02) In them! Same with noc variabile then it should run.

To move data from a numeric field to a COMP-3 field, you need to make sure that the data in the numeric field is valid for the COMP-3 field. A COMP-3 field stores packed decimal data, which means that the digits of the number are packed into two-digit decimal fields. The decimal point is not stored, and the sign of the number is stored in the last nibble of the field.

Answer (score 0):

Like piet.t said, the `UNSTRING` statement is like a alphanumeric move. Therefore my suggestion is to:

1. make `NOA` and `NOB` be alphanumeric (`PIC X(12)`), and
2. change your move statements to include `WITH CONVERSION` so that it will convert the numeric data in the alphanumeric field into `COMP-3`.

Comment: `WITH CONVERSION` isn't part of Enterprise COBOL, so probably won't help the OP.